# Release apk has closed immediately when open in android devices (Recat -native)

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native, react-native-fcm

1. **Android Release apk has stopen when open it in react -native**

   ```
   *****E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3
       Process: com.reactapp, PID: 4023
       java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
           at com.facebook.react.bridge.p.a(Unknown Source)
           at com.facebook.react.k$5.run(Unknown Source)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
        ****Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.react.bridge.ProxyJavaScriptExecutor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.reactapp-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.reactapp-2/lib/arm, /data/app/com.reactapp-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]****
           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
           at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native Method)
           at java.lang.Runtime.doLoad(Runtime.java:1060)
           at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:895)
           at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1505)
           at com.facebook.l.b.a(Unknown Source)
           at com.facebook.l.b.a(Unknown Source)
           at com.facebook.l.g.a(Unknown Source)
           at com.facebook.l.g.a(Unknown Source)
           at com.facebook.react.bridge.ao.a(Unknown Source)
           at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeMap.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
           at com.facebook.react.bridge.p.a(Unknown Source) 
           at com.facebook.react.k$5.run(Unknown Source) 
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)*****
   ```

   1. **What Should I do For That can Any One Help Me For that**

> I am use here react-native-fcm and react-native-device-info in this project

## #

- List item Build.gradle gere

  ## #

  `android {
      compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
      buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

  ```
  defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.reactapp"
      minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
      targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
      multiDexEnabled true

      ndk {
          abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
      }

      packagingOptions {
          exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/librealm-jni.so"
          exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
      }


  }

  signingConfigs {
      release {
          storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
          storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
          keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
          keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
      }
  }
  splits {
      abi {
          reset()
          enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
          universalApk true  // If true, also generate a universal APK

      }
  }
  sourceSets {
      main {
          jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
      }
  }
  /* packagingOptions {
       exclude '/lib/mips64/**'
       exclude '/lib/arm64-v8a/**'
       exclude '/lib/x86_64/**'
   }*/

  buildTypes {
      release {
          minifyEnabled true
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
      }

  }

  // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
  applicationVariants.all { variant ->
      variant.outputs.each { output ->
          // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
          // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
          def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
          def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
          if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
              output.versionCodeOverride =
                      versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  }

  dependencies {
      implementation project(':react-native-fcm')
      implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
  //    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
      implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1"
      implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
      implementation project(':react-native-device-info')

  ```
  /*implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'*/
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
  ```

  }

  // Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
  // puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
  task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
      from configurations.compile
      into 'libs'
  }
  apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"

Comment: Welcome. Please read [making an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then click `edit` to pare your code down to that users can help you, and future users can easily determine if your Q will help them.  Also read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As written, your code had serious formatting errors, and your question is unclear. Remember, everyone here is a volunteer. **Help us help you**  With thousands of unanswered questions, users naturally spend their time on clear, easy to read Q's where the OP has made it easy to see and *understand the issue*.  Best of Luck

Comment: probably it is because of android wrong proguard

Comment: @nima_moradi here is my Proguard
 buildTypes {  release { minifyEnabled true
  proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"} }
And ProGuard rules here (ProGuard-rules.pro)
-ignorewarnings
  -keep class com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.ModuleRegistryHolder { *; }
  -keep class com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.CatalystInstanceImpl { *; }
  -keep class com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.JavaScriptExecutor { *; }
  -keep class com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable { *; }

Comment: show me proguard-android.txt

Comment: buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }

    }
-@nima_moradi